# Datatable exporting values after being deleted

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a table and I want to export the data using jQuery Datatables export buttons, the problem is that I want to clear specific values in specific columns (at the HTML table on browser there is no problem) the problem is when I try to export the data. Datatables is creating file with data that I supposedly erase.

Here is my code:

```
$("#TableId").DataTable({
  dom: '<"top"Bf>rt<"bottom"lip><"clear">',
  buttons: [
    "copy", //'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
    {
      extend: "excel",
      title: "Report",
      footer: true
    },
    {
      extend: "pdf",
      title: "Report",
      footer: true
    },
    {
      extend: "print",
      title: "Report",
      footer: true
    }
  ],
  aLengthMenu: [[2, 3, 5, 1, -1], [2, 3, 5, 1, "All"]],
  bDestroy: true,
  iDisplayLength: -1,
  fnDrawCallback: clearDateValues
});

function clearDateValues() {
  $("#TableId tbody .clearthis").each(function() {
    $(this).text("");
  });
}
```

Here is the [Codepen with my code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MPvNbN?editors=1010)

What I'm doing wrong? Maybe is the updateTable called on **frDrawCallback**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Since the `data` in the table will be exported to excel, we should use DataTable [`data()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell().data()) method to clear the data on **fnDrawCallback**.
2. To preserve ordering, an invisible column is added to store the value for sorting, and the visible column(**Exit Data**) will sort using the data in invisible column.

The above changes is applied in this [code pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ReZXEB?editors=1111). However, the table looks strange if we sort on **Route Exit**.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! The option off add a hidden column to keep the sorting was helpful!!!

Answer (score 0):

Clear the elements before initializing the plugin.

The plugin stores the data internally so clearing the text in the html after it initializes doesn't remove it from the internal data cache. It is that internal data that will get exported, not the visible html text

If the text is empty to start with then the internal cache will be the same as what is displayed

```
$("#TableId tbody .clearthis").empty();

$("#TableId").DataTable({......})
```

You could also remove the rows completely , something like:

```
$("#TableId tbody tr").has('.clearthis').remove()
```

Comment: Yeah, that was what I tried, but It's very important to me the sorting and doing in that way the sort changes.

Comment: Not entirely clear how you expect this all to work. Might need to set up custom sort function(s)